# my css string jumps one line

Tags: css, coldfusion-11

My existing web application uses css div class="medBlutext" for the texts:

```
 .medBluText {font: 0.7em  Book Antiqua, Georgia, Times New Roman, serif; font-size: 12px; color: #0000ff;}
```

When I use this div tag next to a button or other form field like this:

```
        <tr>
          <td align="Right"><div class="medGreyTextbold">Subject</div></td>
          <td>
            <input type="text" name="Email_Subject" value="" class="inputReqText" Required="True">
            <input type="submit" name="emailsend" value="S E N D" class="SubmitButtons">
            <cfif IsDefined("url.err")><div class="medBluText"><cfoutput>#url.err#</cfoutput></div>
          </td>
        </tr>
```

[image]

The error message which is in url.err does not appear at the same line as the submit button but it appears below the submit button. Like there is a break  tag after the submit button. if I don't use the div tag the message appears next to the send button but I need to make the text appear the same throughout so I need to use the div tag. How can I still use this div tag and make the text appear at the same line?

Comment: `div` is a block level element. It will always take up the full width of it's containing element. Which means it is going to start on a new line. You need to use a `span` or some other element that is an inline element and will not attempt to fill up the width of the containing element. Your CSS class should work for any element, it only has font related declarations. You do not have properties like `margin` that will get ignored by an inline element like `span`.

Comment: `div` is a "block", so it uses all the width it can get, so change it to an "inline" tag, like `span`...

Answer (score 1):

Your CSS style only has font properties, there's nothing that prevents you from using it on other elements like a `span`. The difference in styling that you're seeing is that a `div` is a block level element. It will always take up the full width of it's containing element. Which means it is going to start on a new line. Use an inline element like a `span` instead. Since your style is *not* using a property like `margin` and *only* `font` properties both elements should display the same.

```css
.response-text {
  color: #0000ff;
  font: 12px  'Book Antiqua', Georgia, 'Times New Roman', serif;
}
```

```html
<label for="subject">Subject</label>
<input type="text">
<span class="response-text">Some error occurred</span>
```

You can also set the `div` to `display: inline;` to make it behave like an inline element like a `span`.

---

FWIW I would look at using a different naming convention for CSS classes that doesn't use specific property values like *blue*. See my example above. Now, if the text color ever changes to red, you don't have an element displaying red text with a class of `.medBlueText`.

You might want to move away from tables for your form. Not mandatory but they're a lot less flexible than using `div`s. You might even want to work in [`flexbox`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Using_CSS_flexible_boxes).

Answer (score 0):

`<div>` is a block level element which will break into a new line. Use `display:inline-block` instead.

```css
.medBluText {
  font: 0.7em  Book Antiqua, Georgia, Times New Roman, serif; 
  font-size: 12px; 
  color: #0000ff;
  display:inline-block;
}
```

```html
<table>
<tr>
          <td align="Right"><div class="medGreyTextbold">Subject</div></td>
          <td>
            <input type="text" name="Email_Subject" value="" class="inputReqText" Required="True">
            <input type="submit" name="emailsend" value="S E N D" class="SubmitButtons">
            <cfif IsDefined("url.err")><div class="medBluText"><cfoutput>#url.err#</cfoutput></div>
          </td>
        </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Thank you! it's much appreciated